# Creating a file server and WIFI hotspot using a PC

Tags: wireless-access-point, file-sharing

I don't have a WIFI router at home, so I am trying to repurpose an old PC (which has WIFI) to stream files to phones and other computers.

Is there any way I can create such a WIFI hotspot/router & file server without it having an Internet connection ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Linux, but it will take some knowledge.  There are 2 parts to this problem:

1. Making the WIFI card act as an access point.  This is probably the most challenging part - not all cards can support this functionality.  To make this work, you would use the software "[hostapd](https://seravo.fi/2014/create-wireless-access-point-hostapd)" or "[hotspotd](https://prahladyeri.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/how-to-turn-your-linux-machine-into-a-wifi-access-point/)"
2. IP address assignment and local networking - you basically need to turn the computer into a router without a WAN interface.   You may be able to get away with just configuring the PC to act as a [DHCP server](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/DHCP-Server.html) for the LAN.
3. Running a file server - Google [SAMBA](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/install.html).  SAMBA allows Linux to act as a Windows file server.   You may also want to run a web server and allow files to be downloaded that way as well.